# Unable to download Babel Snippets in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext3, babeljs, package-control

I am using Sublime Text Build 3126 for `react-native` development. When I tried to install babel snippets, getting following error,

```
  Package Control

  Unable to download Babel Snippets. Please view the console for more details.
```

This git [solution](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/736) suggests to uninstall and reinstall the package manager. But it didn't worked for me.

Any suggestion appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Did you look to see what the console says? If I had to guess, you're running afoul of the fact that recently GitHub turned off support for older versions of TLS (secure sockets) and Sublime 3126 (which is really old) can't use the newer TLS. If that's the case the console will have a message to that effect, in which case the solution is to upgrade your version of Sublime.

Comment: @OdatNurd Can you let me know that where can I see the console message?

Comment: You can open the console by using `View > Show Console` from the menu.